# Rate of change for no stretch/compression

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, simulation

I am reading about cloth simulation from [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjxroWiq4DHAhVLcI4KHbScDYw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2F%7Ebaraff%2Fpapers%2Fsig98.pdf&ei=l8a4VbGHD8vguQS0ubbgCA&usg=AFQjCNHQwrPT6zWFg0L-UDIsftsv3W3yiA&bvm=bv.98717601,d.c2E).

This is what one of the part says -

[image]

Shouldn't the condition for no compression/stretching be

W<sub>u</sub> = 0

If there is no stretch/compression along `u`, the rate of change along `u` should be 0, right ?

Why does he instead points to a condition -

||W<sub>u</sub>|| = 1.

for same.

Answer (score 0):

$||\textbf{w}_u || = 0$ would imply that the cloth has been compressed to a line along the $v$-direction.

Notice, that the coordinates $(u,v)$ correspond to points on the cloth, in a type of coordinate system that follows the stretching/compression. If you took a sufficiently stretchy piece of cloth and drew a grid onto it, the grid would deform when you stretch the cloth.

When $||\textbf{w}_u || = 1$, we have that the change in cloth position corresponds exactly to a change in spatial position, in the $u$-direction. That is, the grid on the cloth has not been stretched or compressed in the $u$-direction.

Comment: Wu represent the _rate of change_ along U. When rate of change is 0, doesn't that imply cloth is not changing in that direction ?

Comment: Remember that the function 'w' maps cloth coordinates to world coordinates. Since the cloth's coordinates can stretch, the derivative 'w_u' gives us the rate of change of world coordinates. So it tells us how much we move in world coordinates for a given change in cloth coordinates. Here's a simple picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvyazw3rbd3b47x/New%20Doc%208_1.jpg?dl=0